# java/JSON not showing needed value from parsing JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing

Hey all I am trying to get the needed information from a JSON string.

This is what my JSON looks like:

```
{
  "xmlns:jp": "http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/process/1.0/",
  "childNodes": [{
    "childNodes": [{
        "childNodes": ["https://zzzz.zzzz.zxzzxzxz:9443/qm/process/project-areas/_rutR33fwEee_eeo4ry7Vg/members/bob"],
                "tagName": "jp06:url"
        }, {
                "childNodes": ["https://zzzz.zzzz.zxzzxzxz:9443/jts/users/bob"],
                "tagName": "jp06:user-url"
        }, {...etc.....
```

This is my java code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONML.toJSONObject(theReturnedResult);
JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("childNodes");
JSONObject device = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray vendors = device.getJSONArray("childNodes");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

vendors.forEach(o -> {
    if (o instanceof JSONObject) {
        JSONObject crt = (JSONObject) o;
        String blah = crt.getString("tagName");
        System.out.println(crt.getString("tagName"));

        if (blah.equals("jp06:role-assignments-url")) {
            String blah1 = crt.getString("tagName");
            mapHash.put(owner, crt.getString("childNodes"));
        } else if (crt.has("ns6:owner")) {
            //See who's the owner of this TSR
            owner = crt.getString("childNodes");
        }
    }
});
```

The **String blah1 = crt.getString("tagName");** return the 2nd **tagName** but when it goes into the if/than then I can not seem to find it due to it telling me **JSONObject["childNodes"] not a string.**

I am trying to get the URL value that's assigned to the **childNodes**. So I am unsure as how the first String blah = crt.getString("tagName") works but when I try another one in the if/else statement it doesn't return the url - only an error below?

I am trying to get the value **"https://zzzz.zzzz.zxzzxzxz:9443/qm/process/project-areas/_rutR33fwEee_eeo4ry7Vg/members/bob**.

Help would be great!

Comment: I see no attribute `childNodes` that is a string. Only arrays

Comment: 1st array = childNodes. 2nd arrray = childNodes 3rd array = childNodes then get URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is right isn't it ? `childNodes` is not a `String` but an array with a single string in it. So it should be :

```
mapHash.put(owner, crt.getJSONArray("childNodes").getString(0));
```

Comment: This produces a **null**

Comment: Ah I take that back. It does seem to work now :) Thanks Neeraj!

Comment: Well I take that back. It seems to be giving me the same value every loop for **.getString(0)** since its 0 every time. Is there a way to get an index number without having to define one?

Comment: that's because you're using the same key 'owner' in the hashmap. Every time you loop, the last 'childNodes' value in the hashmap gets replaced by the latest value. You should use an appropriate key for the map to get all the required values.

Comment: Still seems to have the same url each time. I'm putting the URL in the first parameter and the name on the second. The URL is unique per person.

Comment: Try debugging like this: `int index = 0; vendors.forEach(o -> {
    if (o instanceof JSONObject) {
mapHash.put(index, crt.getString("childNodes"));
}
})`. Now print the final hashmap and see if it contains all the values. Then you'll understand I guess.

Comment: The issue you have now is more of a logical error which you should be able to debug.